# How do I use two columns in two tables to fill in another in Laravel 5?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-5

I have two tables one `table_response` with the following columns response_id, **organization** etc. The organization is not known.

I have a `table_request` with following columns request_id, organization etc. Here, the organization is known.

I send a request and generate a request_id stored as `request_id` on table `table_request`. This request_id is attached to a specific organization on the same table.

When the response is received I generate a `response_id` and save it on `table_response`.

The request_id and response_id are the same though in different tables.

I just can not figure out a way to use the request_id and response_id to populate the organization on table_response. Like compare request_id and response_id if same then fill that row on table_response as for organization X.

Would someone kindly guide me in laravel5.3?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want update `table_response` with `organization` in `table_request` where `request_id = response_id`, so:

```
update table_response
set organization = (SELECT organization FROM table_request where request_id = '8888' )
where response_id = '8888' ;
```

This code based on:

> The request_id and response_id are the same though in different tables.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try it out.

Comment: export or back up before running this query! @BobMwenda